# Добавления дополнительного условия в цикл bat файла

Tags: windows, cmd, bat

Необходимо в цикл bat файла дополнить условием. Чтобы это условие было впереди.

Нужно добавить следующее

```
cd "C:\Program Files\7-Zip"
7z x d:\load\*.zip -o"d:\load"
copy d:\load\*.zip d:\load\old
del d:\load\*.zip
```

в bat файл

```
:start

IF EXIST *.xml (

d:
cd load
dir /b *.xml > loadxml.txt
sqlldr userid=PET2/123@OL-ORACLE control=loadxml.ctl
copy d:\load\*.xml d:\load\old
del d:\load\*.xml

)
echo имя_файла. missing.

goto start
```

Comment: *Нужно добавить следующее* Ну так добавьте. В чём проблема-то? *в bat файл* Файл - кривой. Где проверяет наличие файлов - непонятно, куда переходит по `cd` - непонятно... должно быть  `IF EXIST d:\load\*.xml` и `cd /d d:\load`

Comment: Т.е. если нет XML - их надо распаковать из архива? Оберните свой дополнительный код в `IF NOT EXIST d:\load\*.xml (..)` и поместите это между меткой `start` и оператором `IF`

Comment: К примеру если эти условия разделить на 2 цикла. Нужно сначала отрабатывал первый цикл(который нужно добывать)
и следом чтобы отрабатывал второй цикл. Если их запустить вместе то задачи не выполнятся. По отдельности циклы работают.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sh
:start
cd /d d:\load
IF EXIST *.zip (
    "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z" x d:\load\*.zip -o"d:\load"
    move d:\load\*.zip d:\load\old
)
IF EXIST *.xml (
    dir /b *.xml > loadxml.txt
    sqlldr userid=PET2/123@OL-ORACLE control=loadxml.ctl
    move d:\load\*.xml d:\load\old
) else (
    echo .XML files not found.
)
```

Comment: Спасибо как нужно работает